# Naruto Music Determination Rasengan

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the music that plays in the movie "Bonds" during the determination rasengan.I hear this in a lot of scenes it also plays again when sauske and the 4 kages meet naruto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is regards to Naruto Shippuden: Bonds, the music that plays during the [Determination Rasengan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laUoslw-xtU) scene is title as [Snowflakes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QEB5CZwfRY&index=29&list=PLA705C60B610D62D2). This is track #29 on the Naruto Shippden: Bonds OST

Comment: I would one up your answer but I do not have enough rep.

Comment: @Hamza Glad I could help! :)